# Can these functions be implemented with serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I just want to use the nodejs and typescript to run serverless framework locally.
And could the two function  in the following be implemented?

1. Create a folder to mock AWS S3 and to watch the the file in the folder to trigger the aws lambda.
2. Run mysql in local and watch the data in mysql to trigger the aws lambda.

Comment: did you try that?

Comment: The first one, you can mock S3 with "serverless-s3-local" plugin together with "serverless-offline". The second, I don't know any plugin. Please, share your serverless.yaml file code, to get more feedback from anyone.

Comment: Thank you ! 
For the second ,I have used the “serverless-mysql” to connect the mysql. 
But don’t know how to trigger a function by mysql event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the yml for the second one. But it didn’t work.

functions:
mysqlHook:
handler: handler. mysqlHook
events:
- mysql: onConnect

Could I use a function that created by myself to do the trigger or set mysql into provider or resource to be used here?